Darboux theorem for Jacobian determinant
for a function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $D$ is a connected open region in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then:
If $\lvert\mathrm{J}{f}\rvert$ has positive and negative values, then it has zero value somewhere.
This is Darboux's theorem if $n=1$. Yet the argument for Darboux's theorem is difficult here because of the lack of order.
Is this true generally? If not, can we add some weaker conditions to make it true?

Check this
